# how to check if product is discounted

Tags: price

How can I know if the product is currently having a discount?

I used this code.

```
if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
   //had a discount
}
```

But it doesn't works.

Comment: I think you need special price ?

Answer (score 13):

The code you mentioned always worked for me. I think it depends how you get the `$product`.
If you do this it should work.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

if you get the products from a collection, get the collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents() //additional filters go here;
```

Now you can loop through the collection and do your check.

```
foreach ($collection as $product){
    if($product->getFinalPrice() < $product->getPrice()){
       //had a discount
    }
}
```

This method takes into consideration the discount provided by special prices and catalog price rules.

*Additional info. A bit off topic but useful:* Here is how you can get the list of products that have a discount

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
            ->addMinimalPrice()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite();

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);

$collection->getSelect()->where("`price_index`.price !=price_index.min_price");
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe you're looking for `$product->getPrice()` and `$product->getSpecialPrice()`.

Comment: This, however will not detect if the product is on discount via a catalog price rule.