# How to get the correct Final Price for Product on Listing?

Tags: magento2, products, catalog-price-rules, pricing

I'm trying to show a discount in my products, so I created a Helper to get the price and the FinalPrice. With those values I suppose to get the discount but I realized the Price and FinalPrice of my products are the same value. Ex:

```
$originalPrice = $product->getPrice();  //200
$finalPrice = $product->getFinalPrice(); //200
$specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice(); //0 or X value when the product has special price config in Products
$RefinalPrice = $product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice(1,$product);// Final Price including Catalog Price Rules
```

am I missing something here? Is there a better way to get those values?

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange :) U need to use `finalprice`

Comment: But It's not correct, I have a 10% discount in my Catalog Price Rules and that discount is not apply in the value that I get from finalPrice. So maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Refer Magento 1 http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13153/how-to-check-if-product-is-discounted Function will be same

Comment: Thank you so much for take your time to answer me, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to get the `final_price` for the product in `/product/view/hero.phtml`.
So that I could display the stickers based on the discount. Below is what worked for me after spending some time in Magento core:

```
$finalPriceModel = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price');
```

It will return the instance of `Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice`. Which has a method `getValue()` method defined to return the amount in float. So to just get the amount:

```
$finalPriceAmt = $_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();
```

I haven't tried this code snippet on `list.phtml`. But it should work as long as $_product is an instance of `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.

Additionally, below code will give you the regular price:

```
$_product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')
```

Haven't tried it for special and tier prices.

Answer (score 8):

We had to get the final price from a CRON process so our solution was first to set current store

```
/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager */
$storeManager->setCurrentStore(1);

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product */
$finalPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
$oldPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getAmount()->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, the way to do it is using getPrice and getFinalPrice from the Product entity as @ankit-shah recommends in his comment, basically if you get the product entity from a Collection still you will need to get the Product entity by the model itself. Something like this:

```
$product = $this->productLoader->create()->load($_product->getId());
```

with this you will get the correct values. Thanks Ankit!